# Error Message for Error State in input

Tags: sapui5

Is there a possibility to define own error messages for an input?

**View**

```
<Input id="inputReferenceId" change="handleChangeReferenceId" type="Text" />
```

I change the state this way:

**Controller**

```
handleChangeReferenceId: function(oEvent){

    if(...)
        this.byId("inputReferenceId").byId("inputReferenceId").setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error);
        //I need a own error message for the inputReferenceId input
    }
}
```

I need a own error message like "*Please fill in a valid Reference Number*" 
Is there a attribute like valueStateText or something?

Answer (score 2):

It works. It was my fault. If the cursor leaves the field there is no valueStateText. onFocus the input field the text appears.

Comment: good to hear it works... just a hint: in this session I described some coole ui5 features of ui5 which might be of interest to you: https://www.slideshare.net/NabiZamani/displaying-serverside-odata-messages-in-ui5-ui5con-2017

Answer (score 1):

Here is a property:
[valueStateText](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.InputBase.html#getValueStateText)

Comment: It doesnt work for me :-(
`self.getView().byId("inputReferenceId").setValueStateText("My Text");`
Nothing happens. Only the border is red.

Comment: you can define it from the XML view in the attribute. This is strange that it does not work for you. Could you share the coding in jsbin or similar resource? Any errors in console?

Comment: I#ve tried it in XML and JS. Nothing happens. I will paste it to jsbin

Comment: It works. It was my fault. If the cursor leaves the field there is no valueStateText. onFocus the input field the text appears.

Comment: @alexP I'd suggest to accept this answer to let others know that this issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you SAPUi5 library version, as this valueStateText property is available from 1.26.0 onwards.

Comment: version is 1.46.8

Comment: can you create a jsbin example, because it should work for you sapui5 version

Comment: It works. It was my fault. If the cursor leaves the field there is no valueStateText. onFocus the input field the text appears.